# Custom Event Listener- un able to understand reasoning behind constance variable

Tags: actionscript-3

I was following a tutorial online to create a custom event listener. i have some of an understanding of how it works, but its still somewhat confusing. i know that public static Constance DEAD:String = "dead" is a variable (a string) that equals the value "dead", however i do not understand why you need to create this variable just so (type:String) can turn into (DEAD:String). for instance, if you get the value "dead" is that just a default value since it could literally be anything? thanks.

```
package  
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class AvatarEvent extends Event 
    {
        public static const DEAD:String = "dead";

    public function AvatarEvent( type:String )
    {
        super( type );
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The value of the string is used by the EventDispatcher to identify the listeners to be notified when the event is dispatched.

The constant is for you, developer, to help you to write clean code, and avoid to create some silly bugs. When writing

```
dispatchEvent(new AvatarEvent(AvatarEvent.DEAD))
```

you avoid the typo that could occur in

```
dispatchEvent(new AvatarEvent(“dead”))
```

and allow the compiler to check the parameter you give to your event's constructor.

To go further, you could use Robert Penner's [AS3Signals](https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals), which was written as a replacement for AS3 custom events. It solves many of the drawbacks of the custom events. By example, it does not use strings to identify events, so you can't have any conflict created by two events with the same type value. And it avoids creating a new object each time you want to dispatch a new event, so it is better for performances.

Comment: I see, so instead of "dead" you would use the constant DEAD since DEAD:String = "dead";  Alright thank you, that clears it up alot.